# How to get all categories of an entity from DBpedia?

Tags: python, sparql, dbpedia, knowledge-graph

I am trying to build a dataset from DBpedia, but I am not super familiar with SPARQL. I think I need to do two things:

1. Given an entity, I want to find all the dbc (categories) to which it belongs. E.g. in the page for [Effiel Tower](http://dbpedia.org/page/Eiffel_Tower), you can see that there are 12 of them.
2. In the opposite direction, given a dbc, e.g. [Landmarks in France](http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Landmarks_in_France), I want to get all the subjects (instances) in the "is subject of" box.

I have looked through some other posts like [post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364851/getting-dbpedia-infobox-categories) and [post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352187/get-place-categories-from-dbpedia-using-sparql), but was unable to apply them to my problems, especially the second problem. I would like some help with writing the SPARQL queries. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Categories of “Eiffel Tower”:

   ```
   SELECT * { dbr:Eiffel_Tower dct:subject ?category }
   ```
2. Resources in category “Landmarks in France”:

   ```
   SELECT * { ?resource dct:subject dbc:Landmarks_in_France }
   ```

The example on [this page](https://rdflib.github.io/sparqlwrapper/) shows how to run SPARQL queries against DBpedia in Python.